# Creating a File Object with File(URI uri) constructor

Tags: java, file

In my application, I need to create a representation of a directory which is the package where the `<class_name>` is contained. In short, I need to create a `File` object which represents that directory.

The code is as follows :

```
Package package1 = <class_name>.class.getPackage();
String string = "/" + package1.getName().replace('.', '/');
URL url = <class_name>.class.getResource( string );
File file = new File( url.toURI() );
```

Now, the problem is when creating the `File` object, this exception is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical.

May anyone shed light and help me solve this?

Comment: What if, as it's almost always the case, the class is in a jar file?

Comment: Why not use File file = new File( url.toString() );  // ?

Comment: I've tried to use rickz helping statement, but it doesn' work. If I use this I'm now facing that the File Object does not exist. Why is this so?.

Comment: What is the path to the directory ?  What does System.out.println(url.toString()); print ?

Comment: Hello rickz, the results of out.println(url.toString()) are as follows --> "file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/HP_Propietario/Mis%20documentos/NetBeansProjects/atsLibrary/build/classes/cat/oai/atslibrary/irb" the class' package is --> "cat.oai.atslibrary.irb". This directory do exist in my filesystem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use NetBeans. So, I can't help you with that. But, if you can use java at the command line, then try using this test code.

```
package rick;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     Test test = new Test();
     Package package1 = test.getClass().getPackage();
     String string = "/" + package1.getName().replace('.','/');
     URL url = test.getClass().getResource(string);
     File  file = new File(url.toString());
     System.out.println(file.getPath());
  }
}
```